# How to span elements without making CSS moving them?

Tags: html, css

I have some centered input boxes.

[image]

I am trying to add text to the right side of the bet box. Here is what happens when I do:
[image]

How can I fix this? I am using the span element to put them on the same line. What CSS property can fix this?

CODE:

HTML:

```
<div class="paper">
    <h2>Play</h2>
    <div class="gamebox">
        <h1><i class="fa fa-btc" aria-hidden="true"></i>itcoin dice game</h1>
        <div class="error" id="error">You don't have anymore bitcoins left. Why not deposit some?</div>
        <h3 id="balance">Balance: 1000BTC</h3>
        <form>
            Bet
            <br>
            <span>
                <input id="userbet" onchange="checkBet()" value="1" type="text" name="bet">Error, that bet is not valid.
            </span>
            <br>
            Chance<br>
            <input id ="userchance" value="50" type="text" name="chance">
            <br>
            <h3>Payout: 0BTC</h3>
            <button type="button" id="dicebutton" onclick="prepareRoll()" style="vertical-align:middle"><img src="Images/dice.png"> Roll dice!</button>
        </form>
        <button type="button" id="autobet">Autobet</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #555;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code you're using currently.

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `span` around the other text and set it's `position` to `absolute`.

https://jsfiddle.net/xuhdy7Lc/